# Can a quadrilateral whose sides (in some order) are in arithmetic progression have an inscribed circle?

Tags: geometry, arithmetic-progressions

> Can the sides of a quadrilateral (not necessarily taken in order) be in arithmetic progression in which a circle can be inscribed?

I tried to think of it, but I can only think of a condition in which all the sides are equal. Are there other conditions possible?

Comment: Any quadrilateral with sides $a$, $a+2x$, $a+3x$, $a+x$ (taken in order) will do.

Answer (score 4):

For a quadrilateral with sides $a,b,c,d$ (in that order) to have an inscribed circle, a necessary${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$ condition is $a+c=b+d$. If $a,b,c,d$ form a non-trivial A.P, then it is impossible for that quadrilateral to have an inscribed circle.

It turns out the condition is also sufficient${}^{\color{blue}{[2]}}$. Given four numbers $a, b, c, d$. If $a+c = b +d$, there are quadrilaterals with sides in that order and having an inscribed circle. In particular, this means given any AP $a, a+x, a+2x, a+3x$; there is a quadrilateral with sides $a, a+x, a+3x, a+2x$ (in that order)${}^{\color{blue}{[3]}}$.

As an example, consider the right trapezoid $ABCD$ with vertices at
$$A (1,2), B : (-2,2), C : ( -2, -2 ), D : (4,-2)$$
Its sides are $AB = 3, BC = 4, CD = 6, DA = 5$. They form an AP $3,4,5,6$ but not in order. One can verify that $x^2+y^2 = 2^2$ is an inscribed circle of this right trapezoid.

In general, a quadrilateral which can be inscribed by a circle is known as [tangential quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_quadrilateral). Its wiki entry has other necessary and sufficient conditions for a quadrilateral to be tangential.

**Notes/References**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - The necessary condition is known as [Pitot theom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot_theorem), first proved by Henri Pitot in 1725.
- $\color{blue}{[2]}$ - Pointed out by Jean Marie. The converse of Pitot's theorem was proved by Jakob Steiner in $1846$.
- $\color{blue}{[3]}$ - Pointed out by Aretino in comment.

Comment: $a+b=c+d$ is a necessary **and sufficient** condition for having an inscribed circle.

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks, I didn't know the converse part proved by Steiner...

Comment: Thanks.. I didn't know the name "Pitot theorem"

Comment: The question said "in some order". They did not have to be consecutive.  So technically the answer to the original question is "Yes".